# Spring MVC Create a Object in @Controller from form in JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

EDIT; It is no a repeated question, I know questions like this was asked before but I tried all of them, maybe I dont understand the solutions, but I need Help, so please unmark my question as repeated please, it is a particular problem.

I'm new with Spring MVC.
spring 2.1.7.RELEASE.

I am trying to make a form, filling it with data obtained in other Controller from the database, and then obtain the data to use in another controller.

I want to create a Object (Transaction) with parameters quantity(int) and receiver(int) from my form, but Spring return an error because cant create the object.

I thinkthe error is in the option tag (jsp).

This is my proyect structure.

### Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Transaction.java

```
public class Transaction {

    public int sender;
    public int receiver;
    public int quantity;
    public String message;
    public Wallet wallet;


    public Wallet getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }

    public void setWallet(Wallet wallet) {
        this.wallet = wallet;
    }

    public int getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(int sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public int getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(int receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String messsage) {
        this.message = messsage;
    }

}
```

### WalletController.java

@Controller
public class WalletController {

```
@Autowired
private WalletService walletService;

@PostMapping("/doTransaction")
public ModelAndView doTransaction(
        @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest session) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    //I want to get here every form parameters 

}
```

}

### JSP

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/doTransaction"
        modelAttribute="transaction">
  <input  name="quantity" id="quantity" />


   <form:select  path="receiver">
    <c:forEach items="${usersList}" var="user">
    <form:option value="${user.id}">${user.name}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
  </form:select>

  <input type="submit" value="Do transaction" />
</form:form>
```

I get this error message:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean
>   name 'transaction' available as request attribute
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'transaction' available as request
>   attribute     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)

I tried this in the JSP but it didn't work:

```
<form:select path="receiver">
  <form:options items="${usersList}"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

Thanks!